# two btn-group to be display on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to show the buttons. I want to show all the buttons on the same line.

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/4mRV3mVJyGGQacrn4EFp?p=preview

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck1">RED    
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck2">BLUE
    </label>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac1">Mac1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac2">Mac2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac3">Mac3
    </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin: 13px;" ng-click="submit()">SubmitValue</button>
</div>
```

I tried to put all the button inside the same `btn-group` but I want space after RED and BLUE buttons are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Remove btn-group.

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck1">RED    
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck2">BLUE
    </label>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac1">Mac1
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac2">Mac2
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac3">Mac3
    </label>
</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin: 13px;">SubmitValue</button>
```

Comment: Please read the question, I want space only between BLUE and Mac1 button , I have specified them in different btn-group. The above example you provided showing spaces between all the buttons..

Comment: updated snippet. Took button out of the group. Is that what you want or you also want submit on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button

```
margin: 0 3px;
padding: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are including bootstrap css. You can check this 
[Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=button-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the solution

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

    <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck1">RED</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="ck2">BLUE</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac1">Mac1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac2">Mac2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-checkbox="mac3">Mac3</label>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="submit()">SubmitValue</button>
```

But if you want to show button smaller try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin-left: 20px;"ng-click="submit()">SubmitValue</button>
```